# Kubernetes client-go informers getting "Unauthorized" error after 15 mins

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, client-go, aws-iam-authenticator

#### What happened?

Kubernetes client-go informers getting unauthorized error after 15 mins.

As per Kubernetes Client Go blogs and discussion we see the client go wil refresh the token after 15 mins but it is not happening. Any way to refresh the token without stopping the informer?

`

```
gen, err := token.NewGenerator(false, false)
if err != nil {
    return token.Token{}, err
}


opts := &token.GetTokenOptions{
    Region:               cluster.Region,
    ClusterID:            aws.StringValue(&cluster.Name),
    AssumeRoleARN:        cluster.AssumeRoleConfig.RoleArn,
    AssumeRoleExternalID: cluster.AssumeRoleConfig.ExternalId,
    SessionName:          "testsession",
    Session:              awsSession,
}
token, err := gen.GetWithOptions(opts)
    clientConfig := &rest.Config{
    Host:        cluster.Endpoint,
    BearerToken: token.Token,
    TLSClientConfig: rest.TLSClientConfig{
        CAData: ca,
    },
}
    dynamicClient, err := dynamic.NewForConfig(clientConfig)

    factory := dynamicinformer.NewFilteredDynamicSharedInformerFactory(dynamicClient, 60*time.Minute, "", nil)  
    gvr := schema.GroupVersionResource{Group: "apps", Version: "v1 ", Resource: "deployments"}

informer := factory.ForResource(gvr).Informer()

informer.AddEventHandler(cache.ResourceEventHandlerFuncs{
    AddFunc: func(obj interface{}) {
        fmt.Println(obj)
    },

    UpdateFunc: func(old, new interface{}) {
        fmt.Println(old)
        fmt.Println(new)
    },
})

factory.Start(ctx.Done())
```

`

#### What you expected to happen?

The Kubernetes Auth Token created by aws-iam-authenticator should be refreshed automatically.

#### Installation tooling

other (please specify in description)

#### AWS IAM Authenticator server Version

AWS EKS Managed service

#### Client information

```
- OS/arch: Darwin/arm64 & Linux/amd64
- kubernetes client & version: k8s.io/client-go v0.25.2
- authenticator client & version: sigs.k8s.io/aws-iam-authenticator v0.5.9
```

#### Kubernetes API Version

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"25", GitVersion:"v1.25.0", GitCommit:"a866cbe2e5bbaa01cfd5e969aa3e033f3282a8a2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-08-23T17:36:43Z", GoVersion:"go1.19", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/arm64"} Kustomize Version: v4.5.7 Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22+", GitVersion:"v1.22.15-eks-fb459a0", GitCommit:"be82fa628e60d024275efaa239bfe53a9119c2d9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-10-24T20:33:23Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"} WARNING: version difference between client (1.25) and server (1.22) exceeds the supported minor version skew of +/-1