# Kubernetes informer fails with Unauthorized

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, client-go, aws-iam-authenticator

I'm trying to construct a Kubernetes informer outside of the EKS cluster that it's watching. I'm using [aws-iam-authenticator](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator) plugin to provide the [exec-based credentials](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins) to the EKS cluster. For the plugin to work, I'm assuming an IAM role and passing the AWS IAM credentials as environment variables.

The problem is that these credentials expire after an hour and cause the informer to fail with

> E0301 23:34:22.167817     582 runtime.go:79] Observed a panic: &errors.StatusError{ErrStatus:v1.Status{TypeMeta:v1.TypeMeta{Kind:"", APIVersion:""}, ListMeta:v1.ListMeta{SelfLink:"", ResourceVersion:"", Continue:"", RemainingItemCount:(*int64)(nil)}, Status:"Failure", Message:"the server has asked for the client to provide credentials (get pods)", Reason:"Unauthorized", Details:(*v1.StatusDetails)(0xc0005b0300), Code:401}} (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials (get pods))

Is there a better way of getting `ClientConfig` and `aws-iam-authenticator` to refresh the credentials?

Here's a rough skeleton of my code:

```golang
credentialsProvider := aws.NewCredentialsCache(stscreds.NewWebIdentityRoleProvider(...))
creds, err := credentialsProvider.Retrieve(ctx)

config := clientcmdapi.NewConfig()
// ...
config.AuthInfos["eks"] = &clientcmdapi.AuthInfo{
    Exec: &clientcmdapi.ExecConfig{
        Command: "aws-iam-authenticator",
        Args: []string{
            "token",
            "-i",
            clusterName,
        },
        // These env vars are static! :(
        Env: []clientcmdapi.ExecEnvVar{
            {
                Name:  "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID",
                Value: creds.AccessKeyID,
            },
            {
                Name:  "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY",
                Value: creds.SecretAccessKey,
            },
            {
                Name:  "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN",
                Value: creds.SessionToken,
            },
        },
        APIVersion:      "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1",
        InteractiveMode: clientcmdapi.NeverExecInteractiveMode,
    },
}

restConfig, err := config.ClientConfig()
clientset, err = kubernetes.NewForConfig(restConfig)

informerFactory := informers.NewSharedInformerFactory(clientset, time.Second*30)
podInformer := cw.informerFactory.Core().V1().Pods().Informer()
```

Here are a couple similar threads I found:

- [Kubernetes client-go informers getting "Unauthorized" error after 15 mins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74563117/kubernetes-client-go-informers-getting-unauthorized-error-after-15-mins)
- https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/1189

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to create write the credentials to a file and create a background thread to refresh that file. I can then pass tell `aws-iam-authenticator` to read the credentials from the file via the `AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE` environment variable.

This might also be possible using `AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE` to save some steps, but I didn't look further.

The updated code looks like this

```
func updateCredentials(ctx context.Context) {
    creds, err := c.credentialsProvider.Retrieve(ctx)
    s := fmt.Sprintf(`[default]
aws_access_key_id=%s
aws_secret_access_key=%s
aws_session_token=%s`, creds.AccessKeyID, creds.SecretAccessKey, creds.SessionToken)
    err = os.WriteFile(credentialsFile.Name(), []byte(s), 0666)
    return nil
}

func updateCredentialsLoop(ctx context.Context) {
    for {
        err := updateCredentials(ctx)
        time.Sleep(5*time.Minute)
    }
}

credentialsProvider := aws.NewCredentialsCache(stscreds.NewWebIdentityRoleProvider(...))

credentialsFile, err := os.CreateTemp("", "credentials")
updateCredentials(ctx)
go updateCredentialsLoop(ctx)

config := clientcmdapi.NewConfig()
// ...
config.AuthInfos["eks"] = &clientcmdapi.AuthInfo{
    Exec: &clientcmdapi.ExecConfig{
        Command: "aws-iam-authenticator",
        Args: []string{
            "token",
            "-i",
            clusterName,
        },
        Env: []clientcmdapi.ExecEnvVar{
            {
                Name:  "AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE",
                Value: credentialsFile.Name(),
            },
        },
        APIVersion:      "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1",
        InteractiveMode: clientcmdapi.NeverExecInteractiveMode,
    },
}

restConfig, err := config.ClientConfig()
clientset, err = kubernetes.NewForConfig(restConfig)

informerFactory := informers.NewSharedInformerFactory(clientset, time.Second*30)
podInformer := cw.informerFactory.Core().V1().Pods().Informer()
```